# How to host SPA in CloudFront with webserver as backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, web-deployment, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on a home project which consists of two parts: web server (Java) and SPA application (Angular + Webpack) that communicate with each other via REST and websockets. At the moment the UI is served by NGINX as static content, and webserver is hosted on the same server as NGINX. It means when user makes request to `mydomain.com` NGINX provides angular static content to user's browser (`js`, `html`, `css`). In these `js` files I have several services that communicate with webserver using relative paths (e.g. `/getPriceList`, browser makes request to `mydomain.com/getPriceList`). So I wonder if it's possible to use something like Amazon CloudFront (CDN) for serving static content and get rid of NGINX? I've just started reading documentation and can't catch how should I configure my UI app in order to work with webserver that is located on separate machine. The desired scenario is when user requests `mydomain.com` he will get all static content (UI app) from CDN. But it's not clear how the UI app should be configured in order to have access to my web server (where should it be hosted, should I still use relative paths and so on). I hope that you caught my question.

Comment: hello, i recommand you to check how assets is loaded in stackoverflow, you will find your answer yourself. After that you will face new issue, how js from `some-domain.ltd` can ask API from `another-domain.ltd` answer is `CORS http header`

Comment: As I understood I can attach my `mydomain.com` to Elastic Application Load Balancer and configure ELB listener to path `mydomain.com/api/`. It means that in my js I should leave relative paths with prefix for ELB `/api/getPriceList`. So when I request `mydomain.com`, CloudFront will distribute the UI, but when this UI requests `mydomain.com/api/getPriceList` ELB will route request to my server. Am I right? And in this case I don't need to configure CORS rules. @Yanis-git